# JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать проверку на вопрос в js с помощью регулярки?
То есть определить, что в конце предложения стоит вопросительный знак.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string1 = 'Предложение какое-то? Возможно';
const string2 = 'Предложение какое-то? Возможно?';
const string3 = 'Предложение какое-то. А вопроса то нет!';

console.log(/\?(?=\s+|$)/.test(string1))
console.log(/\?(?=\s+|$)/.test(string2))
console.log(/\?(?=\s+|$)/.test(string3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как регуляркой, но предложение это string, string это array букв, перебираем

```js
((array.length - 1) === "?")
```